# How to run a loop to get undetermined number of inputs from scanner?

Tags: java, command-line, input, java.util.scanner

I want to take a line of integers as command line input. But I don't know how many integers users will be entering. So how do I stop my scanner object at right time. Is there a method like hasNext() to do so which can be used in while loop?
For ex: My input could be:

```
2 3 4 5
or 
9 1 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) as follow:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
String input=scan.readLine();
String[] nums=input.split();
int[] numbers=nums.length;
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    numbers[i]=Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
}
```

This Code will take the whole `String` as a input and then it will split them and Converts into `Integer`

Comment: If if was helpful to you, then You can Upvote the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use String.split() to get an array of all the input entered. For example:

```
String[] input = in.nextLine().split();
```

Then you can access each element as needed. Hope that helps!